# SharePoint designer 2013 crashes after trying to select people/groups

Tags: sharepoint-designer, people-picker

I am using SharePoint designer 2013. I have a task and I would like to assign this task to some SharePoint user or group. I click on "people/groups from sharepoint site" and than SharePoint designer crashes.[image]

[image]

Comment: Since you have already issued a bounty on the duplicate question, I guess you agree that it is a duplicate :)

Comment: I have here printscreens to make the issue clear.

Comment: You are free to propose an edit to the duplicate post, including your screenshots instead